# How can I plot the power spectra of a ST (Stratosphere Troposphere) Radar in MATLAB to estimate the doppler shift

Tags: fft, matlab, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, radar

Respected all,
I am trying to plot the power spectra of a  ST (Stratosphere Troposphere) Radar to estimate the doppler shift. I am able to obtain a 3D plot between range, FFT point and Power density using the 'mesh' function, but want to obtain a plot similar to the 2nd plot attached below. Which command or process should I use in MATLAB to obtain the second plot?[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is an off the shelf function that can do this but its easy enough to write it yourself with multiple `plot()` commands. What exactly is your problem ?

Comment: Respected Sir, Thank you very much for your kind response. The major problem I am facing is that I have three parameters to plot i.e FFT point, Height and the Power Spectral Density. This is easily obtained in a 3d plot, but how can I show the variation between 3 parameters(namely FFT point, Height and the PSD) in a 2D plot as show in the 2nd figure. The second figure show the variation of PSD with frequency at various heights, where the peak points represents the PSD.

Comment: Besides converting the frequencies to Doppler, it seems all you need to do is plot the first graph so that you view it from the top-down via a rotation.

Comment: Respected Sir, thank you very much for your response. I have tried viewing the 3d plot from the top down, but then it becomes similar to a contour plot of the data rather then the 2nd plot.